# How to reverse the relationship between a cloned repository and its source?

Tags: git

I created a small local Git repository on my laptop to start some work.  After a while I decided I wanted to share it with friends; so I cloned it to a USB key.  When my friends clone from the USB key, their local repository shows the USB key as their origin.  So their pushes will go there (assuming they have the key installed).  But my copy shows nothing when I run "git remote -v" because I didn't create my copy through a clone, I used init.

How do I modify my local repository to treat the USB key as the "new origin"?  I'm brand new to Git so I'm still learning to "think Git".  I have a few guesses how this might be typically done.

1. Remove my local repository and clone it back from the USB key.
2. Invoke some incantation of "git remote add" to add the USB key repository back to my local as the "origin".

Is this a common use-case?  Or is something else typically done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this from your original repository:

```
git remote add origin /path/to/usbkey/repo
```

That should ad a remote with the name origin to the current repository.

Here's a link to the documentation:

[git remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)

Comment: Ah, so option #2.  Thanks for the clarification.  This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote add origin /path/to/sdcard
```

You don't even need to remove the remote from the sdcard: A repository can have as many remotes as you like and two repositories can have each other as remote.

(Sidenote: `origin` is just a name for a remote repository associated with the local one. It is by convention the default remote)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike traditional (non-distributed) version control systems Git doesn't really have a "master" repo... All repos are equal partners...

You can use git remote add to point to other repos...

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to push everything to the USB key, delete your local repository, then clone from the USB key a new local.

Comment: OK.  So option #1 above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do is to look at the file that your friends have for their `.git/config` and copy the relevant parts in your `.git/config`.